# Anybody tried Farm solution in SharePoint 2019 on-premise?

Tags: farm-solution, 2019

It is about SharePoint 2019 Preview (on-premise, server edition, not Online)

Internet says that **code-based sandboxed solutions** are deprecated. But I can't see anything about farm(full-trusted) solutions.

Anybody tried to deploy Farm solution in 2019 Preview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Farm solutions are fully supported, although the Visual Studio tooling isn't quite yet available.

Comment: Can we use VS 2016 or 2013 tooling for deploying SP 2019 farm solutions? Not sure if that's ideal but wanted to know, thanks.

Comment: I believe VS 2017 is the minimum required version.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, understood that part. What about tooling though? With VS 2017, Can we use sharepoint 2013 or 2016 tooling (templates) for creating a farm solution and deploy in SP 2019?

Comment: VS 2017 has tooling for 2019. I guess I don't understand the question. You can develop 2010-2019 solutions with VS 2017.

Comment: Thanks that helps.